# Angular 2 Changing className changes class name and then removes it

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to toggle a class name of a component which gets click.

```js
  toggleActive(event) {
        const parentClass = event.target.parentElement
        debugger
        if (parentClass.className === 'active') {
            if (parentClass.previousElementSibling === null) {
                parentClass.nextElementSibling.className = 'active'
            } else {
                parentClass.previousElementSibling.className = 'active'
            }
            parentClass.className = ''
        } else {
            if (parentClass.previousElementSibling === null) {
                parentClass.nextElementSibling.className = ''
            } else {
                parentClass.previousElementSibling.className = ''
            }
            parentClass.className = 'active'
        }
    }
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li (click)="toggleActive($event)">
        <a href="#/detail/bopis/default/search/advanceSearch">Pick Up In Store</a>
    </li>
    <li (click)="toggleActive($event)"><a href="#/advanceSearch?BOSFS">Ship From Store</a></li>
</ul>
```

The very first time I click an `<li>` it will switch fine. Then unless I refresh the page it requires two clicks to change the class. When I step through the debugger everything seems to work and then it just resets to `className = ""`

I appreciate any help or a better way to do this.

Comment: try to "return false" in the end of your function

Comment: That worked. Any idea why? If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Thank You

Comment: Well it changes the className not but the href is broken so now it won't follow the link when I click. I appreciate you getting me closer.

Comment: What is your 'active' class doing? Showing and hiding element?

Comment: Active class is just changing the display of the currently clicked tab. https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.1/components.html#navs

Comment: I tried changing the window.location.href when the tab gets clicked and it follows the link but then doesn't change the class name at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent default click event of the anchor tag, that's why you need to

```
return false;
```

in the end of your function.